# Delegating to a method defined in an included module

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in Ruby (2.5) to call a method defined in an included module in the same way `super` works for inheritance?

I mean, supposing I have the following

```
class Parent
 def name
  "parent"
 end
end

class Child < Parent
  def name
   "my parent is #{super}"
  end
end
```

When I call `Child.new.name`, I get `my parent is parent`.

How can I achieve the same in the following situation?

```
module Parent
 def name
  "parent"
 end
end

class Child 
  include Parent

  def name
   "my parent is #{???}"
  end
end
```

What should I replace `???` with?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use `super`:

```
module Parent
 def name
  "parent"
 end
end

class Child 
  include Parent

  def name
   "my parent is #{super}"
  end
end

Child.new.name # => "my parent is parent"
```

When including a module, ruby will add this module to inheritance chain.

```
Child.ancestors # => [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Thus, calling `super` in `Child` will call the corresponding methods in its ancestors.

Comment: Nice one. But why does this work? An explanation (even a brief one) would add greatly to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

We are given the module `Parent`:

```
module Parent
  def name
    "parent"
  end
end
```

and the class `Child`:

```
class Child 
  include Parent    
  def name
    "my parent is #{super}"
  end
end
```

As @Tai points out, we can use `super` to obtain:

```
Child.new.name
  #=> "my parent is parent"
```

because

```
Child.ancestors
  #=> [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

In what sense is the module `Parent` the "parent" of the class `Child`? Yes, those are just words, but it is misleading.

Now let's create another module and have `Child` include it.

```
module A
  def name
    "A"
  end
end

Child.include A
Child.new.name
  #=> "my parent is A"
```

because

```
Child.ancestors
  #=> [Child, A, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

We see that it would been clearer to define `Class#name` as follows:

```
def name
  "the last module included is #{super}"
end
```

Let's try one more thing: using [Module#prepend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend).

```
module B
  def name
    "B"
  end
end

Child.prepend B
Child.new.name
  #=> "B"
```

*not* "my parent is B", because

```
Child.ancestors
  #=> [B, Child, A, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

meaning that `B#name` (which does not call `super`) was executed (not `Child#name`). This means the results are meaningless if any modules have been prepended.